# Why won't my python program work?

Tags: python

```
n = raw_input('Enter a number to square')

def square(n):
    squared = n**2
    print '%d squared is %d.' % (n, squared)
    return squared 

square(n)
```

I'm not sure why this program won't run.

Comment: How do you know it isn't running?  If there is an error message, you should add it to the question.  If it gives the wrong output, you should state what the output is.

Comment: You have to return the value to a variable.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: so whats the problem ? any error ? any explain about ?

Comment: What happens when you try and run it?

Comment: what is `"5"**2` given that `"5"*2 =="55"`?

Comment: As in a = square(n) . and then print a

Comment: @rgbimbochamp ... he will get an error ... (that a string cannot be raised to a power)

Comment: which python version are you using ?

Comment: @muthan judging from `raw_input` I would hazard a guess at 2x

Comment: me too, but who knows ;)

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes, he will. i was going to suggest type casting too .

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Shouldn't it return `"55555\n55555\n55555\n55555\n55555\n"`? :)

Comment: @abarnert Someone should submit a PEP. :)

Comment: use of "print" instead of "print()" also points to Python 2

Comment: @khelwood: Then it's time to start bikeshedding; I'm -1 unless `"6"**2` raises `NotANumberError('I will not be pushed, filed, stamped, indexed, briefed, debriefed, or squared')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string ... you cannot square a string (or raise it to any power for that matter)

try

```
def square(n):
   n = int(n) #this will try to force it to be an integer instead of a string
   ...

print square(n)
```

beware if a user types "hello" or something though .. as it cannot convert that to an integer

Comment: yeah ... I guess ... I dont think thats relevant to the question however

Comment: because he is always giving a string to the function ... __it is an error to raise a string to a power__ there is no error in not printing a return ... really thats just something to help debug